# abstract database away for dynamically generated sql in C#

Tags: c#, sql, orm

I'm dynamically importing data into a database where I create new tables on the fly and store the metadata so that I can access those tables later via dynamically constructed SQL. My question is, for C#, is there a library out there that I can use that can abstract away some of the details of the SQL itself? The situation I'm running into is with sequences (although there are others). In Oracle accessing a sequence looks like this

```
select foo.nextVal from dual;
```

In Postgres...

```
select currval('foo_id_seq');
```

For my project I don't know what the final database will be and I don't like the idea of running through the project fixing a bunch of errors due to bad SQL.

I looked at NHibernate and it looks like tools like that (Linq to SQL) require an existing object model in place. I don't have an object model because all of my data is dynamically provided and I don't know the number of columns, data types, etc.

Any suggested approach to this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Dynamically created tables sound like bad news. Is there really no alternative?

Comment: Essentially our clients upload files. We don't know the number of files, the data types, the relationships between them, the number of rows, the number of columns, or anything. We've used dynamic construction for a while with much success.

Comment: Use an XML column for your dynamically generated data.

Comment: I don't want to take that approach because I can dynamically construct the SQL and modify data really fast. Deserialization and searching XML data is time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you're trying to store has a dynamic structure, then it really sounds like a relational database may not be the best choice.  It's strengths rely on data being statically structured and well defined.  You might be better served with a document oriented store like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) which is designed for dynamic schemas.  If you used something like MongoDB, I think your question around abstracting query generation for dynamically changing schemas goes away.

That said, some relational databases like SQL Server have good support for XML data types which allow you to specify an arbitrary structure within your static schema.  SQL Server also allows you to query directly into XML data types [and even index them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx), which means you can query on the server side without the need for transferring the XML back to the client, deserializing, etc.  To decide if this will perform well enough for your needs you'll have to test with data that will represent your production load.